# Encoding German Character in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, encoding, jupyter

I have a data set with German customer reviews that I would like to perform a Topic Model on. I am using Jypter Notebook with Python 3.7.10 and Windows 10. However, I am struggling to find the proper encoding.

```
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

prints `utf-8`

I have tried:

```
with open('C:/Users/TinnerF/Dropbox/ResearchProjects/RawData/LIWC_Output.csv') as f:
    print(f)
```

which yields

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/TinnerF/Dropbox/ResearchProjects/RawData/LIWC_Output.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

To demonstrate the problem,

```
s = df['text'].iloc[0]
print(str(s.encode('cp1252',"ignore"),'utf-8'))
```

produces

```
*Sehr freundlicher Umgang mit den G�sten, kompetentes Personal, alle Reklamationen sofort zufriedenstellend erledigt, hervorragendes Essen*
```

and

```
print(s.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8'))
```

produces

```
*Sehr freundlicher Umgang mit den G�sten, kompetentes Personal, alle Reklamationen sofort zufriedenstellend erledigt, hervorragendes Essen*
```

while

```
print(s.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf8', 'ignore'))
```

producces

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 34: character maps to <undefined>
```

I also tried

```
%pip install ftfy
import ftfy
print(ftfy.fix_text(s))
```

which got me

```
*Sehr freundlicher Umgang mit den G�sten, kompetentes Personal, alle Reklamationen sofort zufriedenstellend erledigt, hervorragendes Essen*
```

In this case,

```
s.encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

yields

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 34: ordinal not in range(256)
```

A sample of the data set can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yR-cDo0asRetgcdlGrCtWHv2xQQwFVe9sk0avrByBvU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The data seems to have been re-encoded several times. You can try  https://github.com/rspeer/python-ftfy - I tested it once long ago and had found it to work rather well then, or search on SO about mojibake, the name given to that kind of text mangling for more manual approaches.

Comment: The `print(f)` simply reveals the file handle object, though it is interesting to note that it says it used CP1252 instead of UTF-8 to open the file. Is the input actually UTF-8 really? (Sorry, no way I am going to log in to Google to open that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\ufffd is the Unicode Replacement Character. It is used when something goes wrong during encoding.

Your data is already FUBAR. There is nothing you can do during decoding to fix it. Fix your data first.

(Well, you can take a guess by comparing the words you have with words from a German dictionary. But I wouldn't recommend it, because it's a lot of work and not guaranteed to yield correct results.)

Comment: Thank you Sören. I generated the dataset again, and managed to finally read it in using encoding= "ISO-8859-1".